Conditional testing in cypress/typescript
Need help with conditional testing of cypress/typescript.
After pressing button ".button1", I need to check for the presence of button ".button2", and if it exists - press it and perform additional actions, if it does not exist - continue the test.
After pressing the button ".button1" there is loading and the button ".button2" may appear in a few seconds (or not). Unfortunately, I cannot control the appearance of the button.
The option with the "Cypress-if" addon didn't help. If there is no button, the test fails.
The option  cy.get('body').then((body) =\> { didn't help because of the delay in the button appearing.

Probably you have some kind of UI informing the User that the first action is still loading, like a spinner. Simply wait for the spinner to not exist e.g. cy.get('spinner').should('not.exist') and then you can use the cy.get('body') trick.
